# Mac pkg installation checks failed

Tags: installation, certificate, package, xcode5

In xcode 5.0.2, I created a pkg using the archive->distribute->export as->mac installer pkg.
The app signing is set to Developer ID.  After the package has been created,  I use productsign to sign my pkg file.  I also tested the newly signed pkg using:

```
spctl -a -v --type install <file path>
```

the package installs perfectly on the machine that I built it on but when I tried installing on a different machine the installation fails with:

```
installation check failure <app name> can't be installed on this computer.
```

I also ran the spctl command previously on the new machine and got an accepted response with source = Developer ID.

How can I fix this problem? Or at the very least does anyone knows how to debug the installation check failure error?  I can't seem to find any logs to determine where the check fails.